# What is the best way to implement a running text log with MVVM / Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a form that facilitates a long running operation that produces a running log. What's a good way to implement this with MVVM / WPF?

I could just bind a string property to a `TextBlock` or a `TextBox` and keep updating it, but that seems like a lot of string generation. Or, I could have a list of strings, keep adding new strings to it and bind to a list box.

Is there a third option or is either of the above preferable to another?

Answer (score 1):

I think, aside from the MVVM consideration with wanting to leverage `INotifyPropertyChange`, it's all a matter of style as opposed to hard and fast set of rules.  Any way you go, you'll be generating new strings for each update so I wouldn't be terribly concerned about it unless memory becomes a constraint and you have to throw away older strings or maintain some sort of current buffer.  You've been considering the approach I usually use.

When I've done this, I've used a TextBox, but I don't have a strong argument on preferring it over the `TextBlock`. I also usually use an `ObservableCollection<string>` rather than a list just for the MVVM `INotifyPropertyChange` goodness, and with each update add it to the collection.

Comment: Yes - this approach or using `StringBuilder` is a much better approach than concatenation - since strings are immutable concatenating a string onto the end of an ever growing string is not the best idea. Ok chances are you are never going to get near the memory limit, but it's just good to know that you are safe(r)

Comment: @Charleh - how does `StringBuilder` fit into updating a running log in UI?

Comment: Obviously I wouldn't use it for a running log, but I thought I'd mention it in case the OP was thinking about doing a single string with line breaks instead of a collection of strings - that way a single `StringBuilder` instance can just be kept in memory and `ToString`ed after any appends are made. It does sound a bit silly though :D (it was more a comment on string concatenation!)